# How can I find my site in the first 5 search results and follow the link

Tags: python, selenium

I tried the below code, but it's not correct exactly. How can I find my site in the first 5 search results and follow the link?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
# driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://google.com")
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.click()

search.send_keys('python')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']//div//h3/a")[:5]
link = first_five[:5].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite')
link.click()

#driver.quit()
```

Comment: what site you are try to find?

Comment: this link https://habr.com/ru/hub/python/

Comment: first you need to know at what position in google search the page exist. Then go to this position and fry to find you page

Comment: why can't you search for the url rather python directly and check of the search result url matching with the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little confusing, but hopefully, I can help.

In your example, it looks like you are trying to:

1. open google and search
2. collect top 5 results and click on 1 of the links => I believe this is what you are trying to do by using this code:

```
first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(".//*[@id='rso']//div//h3/a")[:5]
link = first_five[:5].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite')
link.click()
```

So there are 2 issues I see here: first_five already collects all links and takes top five, because you have `[:5]` at the end of this like. 
And then, when setting link, it looks like you are trying to take the top 5 elements again because you are doing `link = first_five[:5]` and using `[:5]` again.

Also, it is not clear to me why you use this:

```
.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/a/div/cite')
```

You have already found all the elements of the list, why need to search again?

**The solution I'd suggest is this:**

```
# Search
search.send_keys('habr.com python')
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# Store first 5 results
first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='r']//a[.//h3]")[:5]

# Click the result you need by index: if your link in first, use [0] 
link = first_five[0].click()
```

Note, my locator in `first_five` is different from yours, bc I see a different google page when searching, you may want to use the one that works for you.

Hope this helped. Good luck.

*Edited:*

If you need to search for a link to a certain web site from top 5 links, use a for loop and simply search for your url in `href` attribute of the element, if the url matches - it'll click:

```
first_five = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='r']//a[.//h3]")[:5]

for link in first_five:
    if 'https://habr.com/ru/hub/python' in link.get_attribute('href'):
        link.click()
        break
```

Comment: Thank you! But how can I make sure, what i can find my link on the first 5 results? Should i use 'for'?

Comment: Correct, @AlexAnchi, I edited my answer to include that as well, please see above.

Comment: Hello. Maybe you now, how it works in Cypress (java script)?